# redirect third-party logs to log file - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I have a log set-up as below.

```
logging.basicConfig(filename=my_dir+'debug.log', format= message_format, 
datefmt= date_strftime_format,encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

I also have third-party application written in `Java`, invoked from my python application.
Which gives lot of logs written onto `stdout`. Is there anyway to redirect the logs coming from this third-party application to my log file.

I still want to keep my required logs on `stdout`. coming from python app.

Comment: How are you invoking the other application? It depends on that.

Comment: its an .exe , using `os.system`